# The distance between a pair of skew diagonals on two adjacent faces of a cube.

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Say we're interested in the distance between the diagonals $u=(0,0,0)+(1,0,1)t$ and $v=(0,0,1)+(1,1,0)s$ of a unit cube.

The standard formula for the distance between two skew lines $$d=|\mathbf n\cdot (\mathbf a - \mathbf b) |$$ gives $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. That's likely the answer I am seeking. But, since my original, intuitve approach conflicts with this, I don't want to give up on it.

I considered the distance from the center of a face to the center of an adjacent face. That distance is $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. The distance from a cube vertex to the center of an "adjacent" face is also $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ (for example, from $(1,0,1)$ to $(\frac{1}{2},0,1)$ or from $(0,0,1)$ to $(\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2})$). Since the distance between the two lines is unique, I know then that the distance I want is less than that.

Where is that unique segment, perpedicular to both diagonals?

Comment: @Heitor Yikes! Thanks for catching that. But my question still stands as to how to approach the problem geometrically.

Comment: Why do you think the minimal line would be perpendicular to both diagonals?

Comment: @Eckhard Isn't that a fact? The normal is perpendicular to both.

Comment: I think it isn't. In this particular case it makes a 45 degree angle with either diagonal. The minimal line between a point and a line is perpendicular to that line.

Comment: @sasha you were right, I confused $s$ and $t$ in my computations.

Comment: @Eckhard Are you saying that the distance between two skew lines is not the same as th length of the common perpendicular? Isn't the cross-product used in the formula for $d$ for this reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited to get the picture right.

I don't have much to add to André Nicolas' answer, except a picture I quickly drew with Mathematica.

[image]

With a little imagination one can see that the minimal line indeed makes right angles with either diagonal.

The Mathematica code used to generate the picture is

```
s = 2/3; t = 1/3;

Graphics3D[{Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}],
  Line[{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}],
  Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}],
  Line[{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}],
  Line[{{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}],
  Line[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}}],
  {Red, Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}}],
  Line[{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}]},
  {Blue, PointSize[Large], Point[{s, 0, s}], Point[{t, t, 1}], 
   Line[{{s, 0, s}, {t, t, 1}}]}
  }, Boxed -> False]
```

Comment: wow! Would you mind sharing your code? I'd be grateful.

Comment: What's was your reasoning process? My imagination tells me that there's another segment congruent to your blue one. So that can't be the answer.  Edit: after your edit...I think it's starting to make sense.

Comment: Where would that putative congruent line segment be?

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it helped me "see" the solution. Like I said before, I could do the calculation using a cross and dot product--no trouble there; troublesome was seeing where it was located relative to the cube. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

We want to choose $s$ and $t$ so that the distance from $(s,s,1)$ to $(t,0,t)$ is minimized. The square of the distance is
$$(s-t)^2+s^2+(1-t)^2,$$
which simplifies to $2s^2+2t^2 -2st -2t+1$. To minimize, set the partial derivatives equal to $0$. We get $4s-2t=0$, $4t-2s-2=0$.

When we solve the system of two equations, we get $s=1/3$, $t=2/3$.  This identifies the points of nearest approach on each line.

If we substitute in the expression for square of distance, we find that the minimum distance is indeed $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.

There is undoubtedly a much nicer geometric approach.

Comment: Sweet! But I got the same answer using a cross product and a dot product! I'm looking for a geometric approach now.

Answer (score 2):

A geometric approach: we only use the concept of orthogonality.

The two diagonals lie respectively on the lines $\ell_1,\ell_2$ which we write as affine spaces as
$$\ell_1=\langle u_1\rangle, \quad \ell_2= \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}+\langle u_2\rangle $$
where $u_1=(1, 0, 1)$ and $u_2=(1,1,0)$. Now let $v$ be the generic vector connecting the two lines, 
$$v=P_s-P_t=\begin{pmatrix} s-t\\ s\\ 1-t \end{pmatrix}$$ 
Imposing perpendicularity $v\perp u_1$ and $v\perp u_2$ we get:
$$(v,u_1)=s-2t+1=0 \\ (v,u_2)=2s-t=0$$
The solution of this linear system is $s=1/3$ and $t=2/3$. By substituting this in $v$ we get the *direction vector* of the line $r$ on which lies our segment. More conveniently let $u=3v=(-1, 1, 1)$, which represents the same direction. What remains to be found is a point $P=(x_0, y_0, z_0)\in r$ so that we can write

$$r= P+\langle u \rangle=\begin{pmatrix} x_0-t\\ y_0+t\\ z_0+t \end{pmatrix} $$
By imposing the intersections of $r$ with $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ you can explicit out $x_0,y_0,z_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the diagram of Eckhard. Project the entire cube vertically and let the projection of the blue line be $XY$ with $Y$ lying on the edge of the face. $X$ lies on the red line of the top face. $XY$  is perpendicular to the red line of the top face. Thus $XY$ makes an angle of $\frac {\pi}{4}$ with the edge. Draw a line from $X$ perpendicular to the edge containing $Y$ and a horizontal line from $X$ to the edge perpendicular to the edge containing $Y$. Label these two points $P$ and $Q$ respectively. Note that $XP = XQ = PY$ and by symmetry (consider projections in the front face), if $D$ is the leftmost vertex on the edges containing $Y$, $YD = XP$ as well. It follows that $XP = \frac{1}{3}$. By looking at the projection in the front face, we see that the required length is $\sqrt{\frac{1}{3^3}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$